# Wordpress custom search by post type

Tags: search

Is it possible:

If post type is post, search only in post title.
If post type is page, search only in post content.

I was trying in any ways but didnt worked, maybe someone could help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will have to use your custom SQL query though.

Use [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter to modify the query.

```
function posts_where( $where ) {
    if( !is_admin() ) {
        $where = <YOUR CONDITION>;
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where' );
```

Your condition should look something like this:

`post_status = 'publish' AND ((post_type = 'post' AND post_title LIKE <QUERY>) OR (post_type = 'page' AND post_content LIKE <QUERY>))`

You should also make sure, that you will modify only main query and not all of them. You can add filter just before main query (i.e. using `pre_get_posts` action) and remove it just after or even inside this filter, I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try tomorrow, because all day was trying to figure out this ... I was trying in wp-includes/query.php in get_posts funcion... Maybe would be easier to use filter ? how can I implement this ? I am sure that i need to change condition there: $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";

Comment: Ok I have several post types: Forum, reply, topic, post, page. I need that if reply when search in post content, if topic when search in post title, and the others search in post title and in post content ? Did I made right? $search .= "{$searchand}(((post_type != 'topic' OR post_type != 'reply') AND ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}' OR $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')) OR (post_type = 'reply' AND $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR (post_type = 'topic' AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";